# JQuery detects initial height only

Tags: jquery, css

I've built a homepage template with a large background image. The following JQuery detects the viewport height and applies a `min-height` with inline CSS to the `.background` class.

```
// Set viewport height on .background - https://j.eremy.net/set-element-height-to-viewport/
function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.background').css('min-height', windowHeight);
};
setHeight();
    $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
});
```

This is working like a charm. However, I have a problem with smartphones. When I expand the mobile navigation, the caption below doesn't move down. This is because the JQuery only detects the height when the page loads.

Is there a way I can make the JQuery dynamic so it detects changes like an expanding navigation?

Comment: Your jQuery actually is setup to reset the height of the `.background` element(s) when the viewport width/height changes but you're not changing the viewport height/width when you open your mobile navigation. You're also not taking into consideration the mobile navigation when calculating your `min-height`. Also, can't you use `min-height:100%` rather than JS? There is also the CSS `vh` and `vw` units that are based on viewport height and width.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback buddy. I'm not using min-height because this needs to work in older browsers.

Comment: What? Your JS does nothing but set `min-height`. `min-height` is supported back to IE7 btw: http://caniuse.com/#search=min-height

Comment: I need to support IE7 ;)

Comment: I'm a little confused. IE7 supports `min-height`. Do you have some kind of polyfill for `min-height` in JS? Because setting the `min-height` CSS via jQuery just adds `min-height` to an element, meaning it doesn't by itself improve browser compatibility over just using a CSS rule.

Comment: You're right. caniuse.com wasn't showing IE7 for some reason. I'll consider this for my next project. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. That caniuse.com website is a great resource for what is supported in different browsers. There is a "Show All" button just below the feature description that will show older browsers' support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime when You want update background height, then just use `$(window).trigger('resize')`.

**Init code:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function (){

    $('.background').css('min-height', $(window).innerHeight());
});

$(document).ready(function (){

    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```